# kong on minikube: how to access kong admin

Tags: minikube, kong

I am following [this](https://docs.konghq.com/kubernetes-ingress-controller/latest/deployment/minikube/) to configure kong on minikube.

I can see kong related resources created.

[image]

[image]

But how do I access kong-admin UI now, as I don't see any IP, port for it.